# Check If Email Already Exists With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if email already exists with JQuery.

I have this:

```
contactpersonen_email:{
    required:true,
    email:true
},
```

and for message this:

```
contactpersonen_email:{
    required: "U heeft geen geldig email adres ingevuld",
    email: "je email is leeg"
},
```

A user can add more contact persons. And every contact person needs a email address. But the email addresses of the different persons cant be the same. But to do that with rules and messages. This is the complete script:

```
rules: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode:{ 
                                        required:true,
                                        maxlength:6
                                        },

                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "required",
                                        contactpersonen_voornaam: "required",
                                        contactpersonen_achternaam: "required",
                                        contactpersonen_functie:{required:true, maxlength:30},

                                       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres_digitale_factuur:{                                       
                                        email:true
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_vast:{
                                        minlength:10,
                                        maxlength:10,
                                        digits:true
},

                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true
                                        },


                                        contactpersonen_telefoon:{
                                        minlength:10,
                                        maxlength:10,
                                        digits:true
                                        },

                                        contactpersonen_email:{
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true 
                                        },


                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer:{
                                         required:true,
                                         minlength:8,   
                                         maxlength:8,
                                         digits: true

                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "required"
                                    },
                                        contactpersonen_voornaam:"required",
                                        contactpersonen_achternaam:"required",
                                        contactpersonen_functie: {
                                        required:true, maxlength:30 },


                                        contactpersonen_email:{
                                        required:true,
                                        email:true                                      
                                        },                                      

                                    messages: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "De bedrijfsnaam is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: {
                                          required: "De postcode is niet gevuld",
                                          maxlength:"Postcode kan niet langer dan 6 tekens zijn"    
                                        },


          //if(document.getElementById('contactpersonen_canorder_0').checked) { return true; } else { alert('please agree'); return false; }

                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "De plaats is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: "Je hebt geen email adres ingevuld",
                                            email: "Je hebt geen geldig email adres ingevuld"
                                        },

                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres_digitale_factuur:{                                          
                                        email: "Geen geldig email adres"                
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_vast:{
                                        digits:"Telefoon nummer bestaat uit 10 cijfers"
                                        },              

                                        contactpersonen_telefoon:{
                                        digits:"Telefoon nummer bestaat enkel uit 10 cijfers"

                                        },

                                            contactpersonen_email:{
                                            required: "U heeft geen geldig email adres ingevuld",
                                            email: "je email is leeg"   
                                        },

                                        contactpersonen_voornaam:"U heeft u voornaam niet ingevuld",
                                        contactpersonen_achternaam:"U heeft u achternaam niet ingevuld",                                                    

                                        contactpersonen_functie:{required:"U heeft niks ingevuld", maxlength:"Functie naam mag niet meer dan 30 karakters bevatten"},



                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer:{ 
                                        required: "Het KVK nummer is niet ingevuld",
                                        digits:"KVK nummer bestaat uit 8 nummers"

},
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "De naam van de eigenaar is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "Het (mobiele) telefoon nummer is niet ingevuld"
                                    }
                                });
```

Thank you

Niels.

Comment: Although you have not stated it anyplace, it appears as if you're trying to use the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "exists", there are three possible ways you can define "exists".

1. Is the email address **valid**?
2. Is there a user with that email that already exists in your database?
3. Is this email address "real" and can receive emails?

The first question **can** be answered with JavaScript and Regex. The second question needs a database connection and backend language (PHP, Python, RoR, ASP.NET ect) to check your database. And the third question can only be answered by sending an email to that address and having them click a link to validate their account.

1. Here is how you check if an Email Address is valid in JavaScript using Regex:

```js
function validEmail(email){
  if(email.length < 6 || email.length > 255) return false;
  return new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/).test(email);
}
```

2. Here is an example in PHP that checks your DB to see if the email address already exists. This assumes you have a table called `users` which has a field named `email`.

Here is the script you should run to see if the email exists in your Database. For this example let's call it "checkEmail.php".

```html
<?php
  $email = $_GET['email']
  $DB = new mysqli("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "dbname");
  // Check for connection errors herer
  $email = $DB->real_esacape_string($email);
  $resutls = $DB->query("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '{$email}' LIMITT 1");
  if($results->num_rows == 0) echo "false";
  else echo "true";
?>
```

Then in your main HTML file make an Ajax call to this script to check if the email exists:

```js
function emailExists(email, callback){
  $.ajax({
    url: "checkEmail.php", 
    data: {
      email: email  
    },
    success: function(response){
      if(response == "true")
        callback(true);
      else
        callback(false);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I thought I knew what you might be asking until you updated your question and now I am even more unclear. Disregard this answer now that you have edited your question.